# What would be the correct format for adding multiple style changes in one media query?

Tags: css

Was attempting to enter multiple style changes in one media query, and was curious if there was any way to clean up the code and add all the changes into one query as opposed to make multiple queries with only one change.

I have attempted to use both commas and semi-colons as separators, and neither have worked. When placing each style change in separate queries, I have had no issues hence the problem isn't with the specificity of the tags.

```
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
    .form-group label {
        font-size: 20px;
    } 
    ::placeholder {
        font-size: 16px;
    } 
    #fs-frm button {
        font-size: 20px;
    }
}
```

I expect all three changes to be executed, but only the first change actually goes through (the label)

Comment: May be you need to specify media type at least `all`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code was formatted fine, it was a matter of placing the query after I declared the viewport-dependant styles for the last two, as in this case I had them before.